# Flipping algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, brackets

I have a string `s` containing different types of brackets : `()` and `[]` . How can I balance a string of this type with the minimum possible number of reversals ? I can replace any bracket with any other one.

For example : Cost for `[)(]` is 2, it becomes `[()]`. Cost for `[]((` is 1, it becomes `[]()` . `[(])` is not balanced.

A more complex example : `)[)([)())]` can be turned to `([])[(())]` in 4 changes, but can also be turned to `[()(()())]` in 3 steps, which is the least number of modifications to make it balanced.

How can I solve the problem ?

Comment: Please be more specific on the replacement operation. What exactly can be replaced by what? Can brackets of the same type be interchanged or is it possible to replace every bracket by a bracket of the same type?

Comment: One can replace "(" by ")","]","[". ")" by "(","]","[" . "[" by "(",")","]" . "]" by "(",")","[". That is, as I said, any bracket with any other bracket.

Comment: Not sure I understand, could you add a test case (input > output) ?

Comment: @AxelH, Added one.

Comment: `)[)([)())]` can be modified in `[()(()())]` within 3 steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First approach I came with is `O(n^3)` dynamic programming.

Let `match(i, j)` be the number of replaces you have to make in order to make `s[i]` and `s[j]` as `()` or `[]`. So `match(i, j)` can be either `0`, `1` or `2`.

Consider `dp[i][j] = the minimum cost to balance the subsequence from i to j in your brackets array`. Now you will define `dp[i][i + 1]` as:

```
dp[i][i + 1] = match(i, i + 1)
```

Now the general rule is that we take the overall minimum between `dp[i + 1][j - 1] + match(i, j)` and `min(dp[i][j], dp[i][p] + dp[p + 1][j])` for any `i < p < j`. Obviously, the result will be held in `dp[1][n]`. There is a C++ solution (I'll also upload a python program in about 15 minutes when I'll be done with it - not so strong with python :P).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int dp[100][100];
string s;
int n;

int match(char a, char b) {
    if (a == '(' && b == ')') {
        return 0;
    }
    if (a == '[' && b == ']') {
        return 0;
    }
    if ((a == ')' || a == ']') && (b == '(' || b == '[')) {
        return 2;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    cin >> s;
    n = s.length();
    s = " " + s;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= n; ++j) {
            dp[i][j] = 0x3f3f3f3f;
        }
    }    

    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        dp[i][i + 1] = match(s[i], s[i + 1]);
    }

    for (int k = 3; k <= n; k += 2) {
        for (int i = 1; i + k <= n; ++i) {
            int j = i + k;
            dp[i][j] = min(dp[i][j], dp[i + 1][j - 1] + match(s[i], s[j]));
            for (int p = i + 1; p <= j; p += 2) {
                dp[i][j] = min(dp[i][j], dp[i][p] + dp[p + 1][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    cout << dp[1][n] << '\n';
    /*for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j) {
            cout << dp[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

Here you go Python :)

```
s = input()
n = len(s)
inf = 0x3f3f3f3f

def match(x, y):
    if x == '(' and y == ')':
        return 0
    if x == '[' and y == ']':
        return 0
    if (x == ')' or x == ']') and (y == '(' or y == '['):
        return 2
    return 1

# dp[i][j] = min. cost for balancing a[i], a[i + 1], ..., a[j]
dp = [[inf for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]

for i in range(n - 1):
    dp[i][i + 1] = match(s[i], s[i + 1])

for k in range(3, n, 2):
    i = 0
    while i + k < n:
        j = i + k
        dp[i][j] = min(dp[i][j], dp[i + 1][j - 1] + match(s[i], s[j]))
        for p in range(i + 1, j, 2):
            dp[i][j] = min(dp[i][j], dp[i][p] + dp[p + 1][j])
        i += 1

print(dp[0][n - 1])
#for i in range(n):
#    for j in range(n):
#        print(dp[i][j], end = ' ')
#    print()
```

Comment: Awesome, pal !­